# Classification of Reductive groups.

Tags: algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $K$ be a field with a non trivial discrete valuation and with $K$ complete and $\bar{K}$ perfect.

What role do the Buildings play in the classification of reductive groups over $K$ ? Also there already is a classification for reductive groups in terms of root datum, how do the two classifications relate?

I am sorry if the question seems vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ a connected reductive (and let me assume at least quasi-split for simplicity) group over a non-archimedean local field. Then we can associate to it its Bruhat-Tits building $\mathcal{B}(G)$. The building doesn't help you classifying reductive groups (that are already classified as you said), but mostly it gives you a lot of information about the structure of the group itself.

I guess that giving an example is the easiest thing to do, since your question is a little vague.

Let $G=SL_2/\mathbb{Q}_p$. Then its Bruhat-Tits buildings looks like this.

[image]

Here the degree of each vertex depends on $p$ (for example, in the picture we have the building of $SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_2)$ and each vertex has degree 2+1=3).

$\mathcal{B}(G)$ doesn't come as a topological space alone. It is equipped with an action of $G$ via simplicial automorphism. Now, one can for example try to understand what are the stabilizers for the action of $G$ of the vertices of this graph. In particular, one can prove that in this case these stabilizers give all the possible maximal compact subgroups of $SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$.

Now one can ask, among this compact subgroups which ones are conjugates? We know that for $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ there is only one maximal compact subgroup up to conjugacy given by $SO_2(\mathbb{R}).$ Is it the same for $SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$? And finally, can the building help us understanding this?

Well the answer to the last question is yes. If two vertices $x,y\in\mathcal{B}(G)$ are conjugate under the action of $G$, then the associated maximal compact subgroup $K_x:=Stab_G(x)$ and $K_y=Stab_G(y)$ are going to be conjugate to each other. And now, studying the action of $G$ on $\mathcal{B}(G)$ one can notice that a vertex can't be send to an adjacent one by $G$, but it can be sent to the ones that are 2 vertices away. This means that in $SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ we have 2 classes of maximal compact subgroup. This are explictly given by the representatives $K=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbb{Z}_p &\mathbb{Z}_p\newline \mathbb{Z}_p &\mathbb{Z}_p\end{pmatrix}$ and $K'=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbb{Z}_p &p\mathbb{Z}_p\newline p^{-1}\mathbb{Z}_p &\mathbb{Z}_p\end{pmatrix}.$